# R - filter observations that remain the same over multiple years

Tags: r, data.table, character, lag, dcast

I have prepared an example data.table:

```
testTable <- data.table(years = rep(c(rep((2014),3),rep((2015),3), rep((2016),3)), 2), 
                        policy = c(rep("A", 9), rep("B",9)),
                        destination = rep(c("Paris", "London", "Berlin"), 6))

testTable[c(1,5,8), destination := c("Moskaw", "Milano", "Valencia")]

> testTable
    years policy destination
 1:  2014      A      Moskaw
 2:  2014      A      London
 3:  2014      A      Berlin
 4:  2015      A       Paris
 5:  2015      A      Milano
 6:  2015      A      Berlin
 7:  2016      A       Paris
 8:  2016      A    Valencia
 9:  2016      A      Berlin
10:  2014      B       Paris
11:  2014      B      London
12:  2014      B      Berlin
13:  2015      B       Paris
14:  2015      B      London
15:  2015      B      Berlin
16:  2016      B       Paris
17:  2016      B      London
18:  2016      B      Berlin
```

Here, i only want to keep observations that have the same `destination` over all years available in the data. In this example i have chosen policies with 3 years only, but the real data may as well have 2,3 and 4 years of history mixed in a single data.table.

The desired result is:

```
> testTable
    years policy destination
 3:  2014      A      Berlin
 6:  2015      A      Berlin
 9:  2016      A      Berlin
10:  2014      B       Paris
11:  2014      B      London
12:  2014      B      Berlin
13:  2015      B       Paris
14:  2015      B      London
15:  2015      B      Berlin
16:  2016      B       Paris
17:  2016      B      London
18:  2016      B      Berlin

Any ides?
```

I tried using `dcast()`, and then i wanted to filter those rows that have the same entries in all columns after `policy`, however i realised that `dcast()` automatically converts my character variable `destination` into numeric and aggregates my data using length:

```
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
```

NOTE: my data will have couple of hundreds of observations.

Comment: So you want to keep only destinations, which are repeated EVERY year? And drop if they appear less? Correct?

Comment: exactly, @Rookie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can filter those common `destination` which is present in each `years` for each `policy`.

```
library(data.table)

testTable[testTable[, destination %in% 
                      Reduce(intersect, split(destination, years)), policy]$V1]


#    years policy destination
# 1:  2014      A      Berlin
# 2:  2015      A      Berlin
# 3:  2016      A      Berlin
# 4:  2014      B       Paris
# 5:  2014      B      London
# 6:  2014      B      Berlin
# 7:  2015      B       Paris
# 8:  2015      B      London
# 9:  2015      B      Berlin
#10:  2016      B       Paris
#11:  2016      B      London
#12:  2016      B      Berlin
```

and in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)

testTable %>%
  group_by(policy) %>%
  filter(destination %in% Reduce(intersect, split(destination, years)))
```

Answer (score 2):

This should solve it

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'data.table'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     between, first, last
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     transpose

testTable <- data.table(years = rep(c(rep((2014),3),rep((2015),3), rep((2016),3)), 2), 

                        policy = c(rep("A", 9), rep("B",9)),
                        destination = rep(c("Paris", "London", "Berlin"), 6))

testTable[c(1,5,8), destination := c("Moskaw", "Milano", "Valencia")]

testTable %>%
  mutate(distinct_years = n_distinct(years)) %>% 
  group_by(policy,destination) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(years) ==distinct_years)
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#> # Groups:   policy, destination [4]
#>    years policy destination distinct_years
#>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>                <int>
#>  1  2014 A      Berlin                   3
#>  2  2015 A      Berlin                   3
#>  3  2016 A      Berlin                   3
#>  4  2014 B      Paris                    3
#>  5  2014 B      London                   3
#>  6  2014 B      Berlin                   3
#>  7  2015 B      Paris                    3
#>  8  2015 B      London                   3
#>  9  2015 B      Berlin                   3
#> 10  2016 B      Paris                    3
#> 11  2016 B      London                   3
#> 12  2016 B      Berlin                   3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's another data.table approach:

```
dt[, if(all(unique(dt$years) %in% years)) .SD, by = .(policy, destination)]
#     policy destination years
#  1:      A      Berlin  2014
#  2:      A      Berlin  2015
#  3:      A      Berlin  2016
#  4:      B       Paris  2014
#  5:      B       Paris  2015
#  6:      B       Paris  2016
#  7:      B      London  2014
#  8:      B      London  2015
#  9:      B      London  2016
# 10:      B      Berlin  2014
# 11:      B      Berlin  2015
# 12:      B      Berlin  2016
```